# System.ObjectDisposedException: handle is destroyed

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-platform

Kafka consumer application is throwing ObjectDisposedException when we initiate the process to stop the consumer service.I would like to understand what process destroyed the kafka handle

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: handle is destroyed
at Confluent.Kafka.Impl.SafeKafkaHandle.ThrowIfHandleClosed()
at Confluent.Kafka.Consumer`2.Consume(Int32 millisecondsTimeout)
at Confluent.Kafka.Consumer`2.Consume(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Answer (score 1):

in my case this exception was thrown in .Net Library Confluent Kafka.
If you are also using this library, please make sure what you call Consumer.Close() BEFORE Consumer.Dispose().